# App Store server notifications always sending notificationType TEST in Sandbox

Tags: testing, app-store-connect, sandbox, storekit, mac-app-store

We have a Mac application that we're migrating to the App Store, and we're testing App Store server notifications and running in Sandbox.  We've set up all of the appropriate URL's in App Store Connect, and testing by using the https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/notifications/test link works great.  We get the notification at our server with a notificationType of TEST.

However, we then go through our application and do a Sandbox test purchase.  It finishes fine, BUT the only notification we EVER get at our server is notificationType TEST.  We assumed that in the Sandbox environment we would get SUBSCRIBED or similar, but that's not happening.  Always TEST.

A few notes.... our app is Objective C (rewriting in Swift really isn't an option currently), and it's using the original Storekit.  We have set up App Store Connect to send V2 notifications since V1 is deprecated.

All the normal processes work from the app, from logging in our Sandbox tester, to completing the purchase.  Our app itself receives a successful SKPaymentTransaction.

We set up the Sandbox User to do a monthly renewal every 5 minutes.  We are getting notifications every 5 minutes for 12 total, but they're ALL notificationType TEST.

Is there some sandbox testing setup we're missing to get actual notifications like SUBSCRIBED and EXPIRED (albeit with the data-environment set to Sandbox)?